# Auto function returning value using switch

Tags: c++, return-type, auto, type-deduction

I'm trying to create a function which return type should depend on switch statement, something like:

```
auto function_name (int value) {
    switch (value) {
        case 1 : {return 2.3;}
        case 2 : {return 1;}
        case 3 : {return "string";}
    }
}
```

But I can't because of an error:

```
error: inconsistent deduction for auto return type: 'double' and then 'int'
```

What can I do to create something similar by functionality to the example above?

Comment: You can't do this for multiple reasons. `auto` has to be known at compile time.

Comment: `C++` is  a statically typed language.

Comment: You might be interested in `std::variant`.

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve with this? That is simply not how types work in C++. While you could use a _std::variant_, I'm hesitant to recommend it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A function in C++ can only have a single type that it returns.  If you use `auto` as the return type and you have different return statements that return different types then the code is ill-formed as it violates the single type rule.

This where [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) or [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) needs to be used.  If you have a few different types that could be returned via some run-time value then you could use either of those types as "generic type".  `std::variant` is more restrictive as you have to specify the types it could be, but it also less expensive then `std::any` because you know what types it could be.

```
std::variant<double, int, std::string> function_name (int value) {
    using namespace std::literals::string_literals;
    switch (value) {
        case 1 : {return 2.3;}
        case 2 : {return 1;}
        case 3 : {return "string"s;} // use ""s here to force it to be a std::string
    }
}
```

Will let you return different types.

Comment: `std::variant<auto>` would be pretty nice, though.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz And have it gather all the types the return statements use?  That would be cool.

Comment: would have to change `"string"` by `"string"s` though then.

Comment: IMO this answer should mention that this is possibly/likely the wrong way. `variant` is the right tool in specific cases, but it can easily be an indicator of a design flaw. Yes, I know, you can't tell exactly from the question, but I find it worth mentioning. Otherwise the asker is potentially left trying to recover from halfway (or fully, with `any`) leaving the type system which leads to more abuse.

Comment: @Jarod42 That was bugging me too.  I was editing when you commeted.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Using `std::variant` isn't "leaving the type system", even half-way. It's still validated in compile time.

Comment: @NathanOliver Interestingly enough, the [template-deduction-based version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef2a58f9f0b3e26e) is kinda close, it just deducts badly.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz With that there is no way to deduce `T...` so the return type just becomes `std::variant<>`.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Call it circumventing if you want. I am not trying to say that `std::variant` always ditches the type system, just that it can be (ab)used to emulate that purpose. It's either elegant (especially with `visit`) or indicative of a design flaw that causes more pain down the road (such as dealing with exceptions or possible `nullptr`s that would be impossible if one stuck with more "direct" typing).

Answer (score 6):

If the function argument is known at compile time, you can use a compile time dispatch like e.g.

```
template <int N>
constexpr auto function_name()
{
   if constexpr(N == 1)
      return 2.3;
   else if constexpr (N == 2)
      return 1;
   else
      return "string";
}
```

which can be instantiated and invoked as follows

```
std::cout << function_name<1>() << "\n";
```

C++17 is necessary for the `if constexpr` part. Note that when binding the return value to a variable, carefully choose the type (e.g. to not implicitly convert a `double` to an `int` by accident), use type deduction or a `variant`-type as shown in the existing answers.

Note that as @NathanOliver pointed out in the comments, there is also a pre-C++17 solution that uses template specialization instead of `if constexpr`:

```
template <int N> constexpr auto function_name() { return "string"; }
template <> constexpr auto function_name<1>() { return 2.3; }
template <> constexpr auto function_name<2>() { return 1; }
```

The usage of this template and its specializations does not differ from the above.

Answer (score 2):

The error message says it all: all branches of the function must return the same type. This limitation is not specific to `auto` return type.

One possible fix:

```
std::variant<double, int, std::string> function_name(int value) {
    switch(value) {
    case 1 : return 2.3;
    case 2 : return 1;
    case 3 : return "string";
    default: throw;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `boost::variant`.

Comment: There is a [standard variant type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) now.